Movie about aliens abducting humans and rebellion against aliens

When aliens abduct humans, people are held in prison, they eat liquid like food and strongest guy gets all food, then one guy beats him and grabs handful of that and shares it to everyone, then he teaches them maths and trigonometry so they can pilot airplanes (f-22 or something like that)
Aliens sit in the bar and chat, they
drink green fluorescent booze, one alien grabs 3 glasses and goes
away.
Aliens look exactly like humans, they wear dreads and something on nose, to block breathing with nose or similar, don't remember
Main protagonist also pretends to be alien by wearing same thing on nose to prove "that he doesn't need to breathe" or similar motiff 
Aliens refer to people as "livestock", "livestock-people" or similar

Movie was produced roughly around 2000s maybe in 90.

Welcome to the community. Any other plot details? If you know, please also describe when you saw it, language, country and year of production, descriptions of actors, color or BW, etc. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

This sounds a lot like "Battlefield Earth", from 2000.  It starred John Travolta, Barry Pepper, and Forest Whitaker.  John Travolta's alien dreadlocks and nasal breathing device can be seen here:

Here is Forest Whittaker in the movie holding the fluorescent green drink you mentioned:


Damn....pipped by a couple of seconds.

I cheated a bit -- I added a pretty good answer quickly, then came back and spruced it up a bit.

you guessed, but why so many downvotes ?

@AltarofDisgraceMusic I don't know why there are downvotes. Try looking at some other "identify this movie" questions that have gotten more upvotes. Maybe you will notice a difference in the way they're written.
